# Issues with ylim when combining pandas plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having an issue with the scale of my y-axis when combining an area plot with a line plot in Pandas.

here is an example to illustrate it:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
for col in ["A", "B", "C"]:
    df[col]=df[col]*1000
df["D"]=df["D"]*5000

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(28, 10))
ax=df[["A", "B", "C"]].plot.area(ax=ax)
ax=df["D"].plot.line(ax=ax, color='red')
print(ax.get_ylim())
ax.margins(0, 0)
ax.legend_.remove()
plt.show()
```

result of `ax.get_ylim()` is: `(0.0, 4917.985892131057)`

and the graph looks like:

[image]

As you can see the graph is cropped at the top and I am missing information regarding the plot D. The expected result would be:

[image]

and in that case `get_ylim()` is `(-613.14902407399052, 16197.881540891121)`.

I have obtained this second graph by inputting manually the ylim.

Could you let me know what am I doing wrong? Why could I not get the `y_lim` from my "D" plot in my example?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to autoscale the graph after adding all plots to it.

```
ax.autoscale()
```

In order for the bottom of the data sitting tight to zero in y direction you can use `ax.set_ylim(0,None)` and for x direction `ax.margins(x=0)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
for col in ["A", "B", "C"]:
    df[col]=df[col]*1000
df["D"]=df["D"]*5000

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax=df[["A", "B", "C"]].plot.area(ax=ax)
ax=df["D"].plot.line(ax=ax, color='red')

ax.get_legend().remove()

ax.autoscale()
ax.set_ylim(0,None)
ax.margins(x=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is becuase the limits are set initally by the first set of data plotted.  Try switching them around:

```
ax=df["D"].plot.line(ax=ax, color='red')
ax=df[["A", "B", "C"]].plot.area(ax=ax)
```

But again this depends on the data, it will only work if `"D"` is always bigger than the others.  You could add a line to automatically update the `ylim` like this:

```
ax.set_ylim(top=df.values.max())
```

Comment: I have noticed that as well. I didn't want to change the order as when there are overlaps between the two plots, the line plot is hidden. Your second option may be the way to go. It is not really convenient to use but that will do for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the y axis limits using `ax.set_ylim()`. But I think the best way wouyld be to use `ax.autoscale()` as suggested by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(28, 10))
ax.set_ylim(0, df.max().max()) # setting the upper y_limit to the maximum value in the dataframe
df[["A", "B", "C"]].plot.area(ax=ax)
df["D"].plot.line(ax=ax, color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image]